# Weighted ergodic averages for a rotation

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $a_{N,k}$ be non-negative numbers for $N,k = 0, 1, \ldots$, satisfying 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{N,k} =1 
$$
for every $N$.

Let $T$ be the rotation of irrational angle $\gamma$. 
Define the weighted averages 
$$
S_N(f) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{N,k} f \circ T^k.
$$
Say that the weights $a_{N,k}$ are *good* if 
$S_N(f) \overset{L^2}{\longrightarrow} \int f$ for every 
$f \in L^2$.

The following result is known: if the weights are good, then 
$$
(\star)\colon \quad \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \in Q_{b}}}^\infty a_{N,k} = b
$$
for every $b \in (0,1)$, where 
$$
Q_{b} = \bigl\{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid \{k\gamma\} \leq b \bigr\}.  
$$

Conversely, is it true that $(\star)$ implies that the weights are good ?